# loopback.io multiple includes

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a loopback.io API with a MongoDB database. 
I have a model called **Project** with 2 hasMany relationships

- **Project** has many **ProjectArticle** objects
- **Project** has many **ProjectWorkHours** objects

When I run I do a request: http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Projects?filter[include][projectArticles]

I get the following response, which is good

```
{
    "title": "Project 1",
    "description": "My project number one",
    "dateCreated": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "id": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8",
    "projectArticles": [
      {
        "articleName": "brick",
        "quantity": 5,
        "unitPrice": 2,
        "id": "5634b9ea5ab833960c8fbf6d",
        "projectId": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8"
      }
    ]
  }
```

and when I do: http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Projects?filter[include][workHours] I get the right answer:

```
{
    "title": "Project 1",
    "description": "My project number one",
    "dateCreated": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "id": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8",
    "workHours": [
      {
        "description": "blabla",
        "startDate": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "id": "5634e11d5f6471f10d2e0dd7",
        "workHourId": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8"
      },
      {
        "description": "blabla 2",
        "startDate": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "id": "5634e1265f6471f10d2e0dd8",
        "workHourId": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8"
      }
    ]
  }
```

but how do i combine the two includes in one request? so I have the following result:

```
{
    "title": "Project 1",
    "description": "My project number one",
    "dateCreated": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "id": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8",
    "workHours": [
      {
        "description": "blabla",
        "startDate": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "id": "5634e11d5f6471f10d2e0dd7",
        "workHourId": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8"
      },
      {
        "description": "blabla 2",
        "startDate": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "id": "5634e1265f6471f10d2e0dd8",
        "workHourId": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8"
      }
    ],
    "projectArticles": [
      {
        "articleName": "brick",
        "quantity": 5,
        "unitPrice": 2,
        "id": "5634b9ea5ab833960c8fbf6d",
        "projectId": "5634b3af340faf570c7e70a8"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried this: http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Projects?filter[include][workHours]&[include][projectArticles] but it only applies the first one and the second filter is kind of ignored

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the syntax for doing it

```
 http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Projects?filter={"include":["workHours", "projectArticles"]}
```

Comment: if you continue reading the docs: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter. You can also use REST as you were using before `/customers?filter[include]=projectArticles&filter[include]=workHours`

Comment: Any idea which solution has the preference? Mine with the JSON syntax or the one with sqaure brackets? I guess that eventually it's translated to the same stuff  before querying the database?

Comment: you can use whichever suits you. it's just personal preference. i just wrote it cause you were using REST one. I use filter query one because it's more understandable to me.